# how to print out the row.names separated by "," and without " "?

Tags: r

my **data** was presented as:

```
        [,1] [,2] [,3]
    aa    1    3    5
    bb    2    4    6
```

I would like to have

```
 > aa,bb
```

but the **rownames(data)** turn out

> "aa" "bb"

Comment: `toString(row.names(data))`?

Comment: or `paste( row.names( data ), collapse = ", " )`

Comment: Great. That is it. Thanks a lot.